# VBA Debug code for using a partial name match to copy and paste between active/open workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I found this code in another thread here but can't get it working in my book... 
What I'm trying to achieve is... The macro to be called from a wb called "SHIFT REPORT*" which looks for and switches to a wb called "PlayerTransactionReport*" to copy some data before switching back to the SHIFT REPORT and pasting it in.

The code I have is:

```
Sub Import_Data()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ShiftReport As Workbook
    Dim PlayerTransactionReport As Workbook

    Set ShiftReport = ThisWorkbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
     If Left(wb.Name, 23) = "PlayerTransactionReport" Then Set PlayerTransactionReport = wb
    Next

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Columns("A:Z").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Set PlayerTransactionReport = ThisWorkbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If Left(wb.Name, 10) = "ShiftReport" Then Set ShiftReport = wb
    Next

    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Currently, it's not setting the PlayerTransactionReport to the active wb but throughout the process of debugging this by myself I've had various degrees of success, but I fear that this one might have between me, Please Help!

Thanks, Stuart

Comment: Why are you *'setting the PlayerTransactionReport to the active wb'* when you set it earlier?

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer to the Parent Worksheet, whenever you are refering to `Sheets()` and `Columns()`:

```
Sub Import_Data()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ShiftReport As Workbook
    Dim PlayerTransactionReport As Workbook

    Set ShiftReport = ThisWorkbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If Left(wb.Name, 23) = "PlayerTransactionReport" Then Set PlayerTransactionReport = wb
    Next



    PlayerTransactionReport.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Columns("A:Z").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Set PlayerTransactionReport = ThisWorkbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If Left(wb.Name, 10) = "ShiftReport" Then Set ShiftReport = wb
    Next

    PlayerTransactionReport.Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

If you do not refer to the parent worksheet, then the `ActiveSheet` or the sheet where the code is, is the one referred.

As a next step you can improve the following 2 points:

- [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
- Check whether the `PlayerTransactionReport` is not Nothing, before calling it:

---

```
If Not PlayerTransactionReport Is Nothing Then
    PlayerTransactionReport.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Columns("A:Z").Select
    Selection.Copy
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

[Stop using Select and Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

```
Sub Import_Data()

    Dim w As long
    Dim PlayerTransactionReport As Workbook, ShiftReport As Workbook

    Set ShiftReport = ThisWorkbook
    For w = 1 to Workbooks.count
        If Left(Workbooks(w).Name, 23) = "PlayerTransactionReport" Then
            Set PlayerTransactionReport = Workbooks(w)
            exit for
        end if
    Next w

    if w > Workbooks.count then
        debug.print "cannot find PlayerTransactionReport"
        exit sub
    end if

    PlayerTransactionReport.workSheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:Z").Copy _
      destination:=ShiftReport.workSheets("Data").Range("A1").

End Sub
```